# Color en Fila DataGridView cuando Marque la casilla CheckBoxColumn, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid, visual-studio-2010

Estoy dando color a la fila del `DataGridView` si la casilla de la celda esta seleccionada, he creado una función la cual la invoco en el evento `CellValueChanged` del `DataGridView` funciona bien, pero solo cuando es el usuario que selecciona la casilla, **si la casilla viene seleccionada desde la base de datos, no colorea la fila.**

> Ahora lo he hecho con el evento `CellFormatting` pero este se mantiene ejecutandose en todo momento y en la interfaz se muestran las celdas **Parpadendo en todo Momento** durante el tiempo de ejecución.
>    **¿Existe alguna otra manera de hacerlo sin usar el evento CellFormatting?**

Datos Seleccionados desde la Base de Datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar estan seleccionadas, pero las filas no toman el color.

Cuando el usuario Marca/Desmarca la casilla: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Función:

```
private void colorFila(DataGridView datagrid)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
     {
         if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagrid.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value) == true)
         {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
         }
         else
         {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
         }
     }
 }
```

Evento:

```
private void dgridDepartamentos_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     colorFila(dgridDepartamentos);
}
```

> He creado una función debido a que tengo varios `DataGridView`semejantes para poder reutilizar la misma función.

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms) & .NET NetFramework 4

Comment: El evento *DataBindingComplete* se produce cuando finaliza una operación de enlace de datos. Usa ese evento para recorrer las filas del *DataGridView* y colorear las que lo precisen.

Comment: Luego que le asigno el DataSource he intentado recorrer las filas, pero no las colorea de todas formas.

Answer (score 1):

una posible solución al problema  que planteas puede ser marcar el checkbox a medida que vas cargando la grilla. Para este ejemplo cree una clase llamada Area que luego utilizo para cargar la grilla manualmente

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public class Area
    {
        private int code;
        private String name;
        private Boolean mark;
        public Area(int code, String name,Boolean mark)
        {
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
            this.mark = mark;

        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        public int getCode()
        {
            return this.code;
        }
        public Boolean getMark()
        {
            return this.mark;
        }
    }
}
```

Luego en el programa principal cargo la grilla por medio de loadData y asigno el valor booleano al CheckBox según corresponda. Como resultado de esto el evento CellValueChanged es invocado y por ende el manejador, lo que deriva en el cambio de color de la fila.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            update();
        }
        private void update()
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Codigo";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Descripcion";
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            chk.HeaderText = "Mark";
            chk.Name = "chk";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);

            loadData();

        }
        private void loadData()
        {

            List<Area> listaArea = new List<Area>();
            listaArea.Add(new Area(3105, "ADMINISTRACION", true));
            listaArea.Add(new Area(3140, "FINANZAS", true));
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (Area area in listaArea)
            {
                ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
                row.Add(area.getCode());
                row.Add(area.getName());
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
                dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["chk"].Value = area.getMark();
                counter = counter + 1;
            }


        }
        private void colorFila(DataGridView datagrid)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(datagrid.Rows[row.Index].Cells["chk"].Value) == true)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                }
            }
        }


        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            colorFila(dataGridView1);
        }
    }
}
```

Ejecución. Como resultado marca en verde los registros cargados como true. Por supuesto que tambien funciona OK a medida que los vas seleccionando/deseleccionando. Tiene las dos filas coloreadas ya que las cargue de esta manera (la marca es verdadera para ambos registros)

```
 listaArea.Add(new Area(3105, "ADMINISTRACION", true));
 listaArea.Add(new Area(3140, "FINANZAS", true));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Buen ejemplo, pero para usarlo tendría que cambiar toda la estructura que tengo hecha hasta el momento en todas las partes del sistema donde coloreo las filas.

Comment: Cuando cargas la rejilla ¿le pones las marcas en los registros que las tengan? Porque si hay registros marcados entonces en el DataBindingComplete podrías ejecutar tu método colorFila().